# Initializing a specific subclass based on input

Tags: c++, interface

I want to initialize a specific subclass based on if a user calls a program with -m or -f.

I've written an interface like this:

```
class DatabaseInterface {

   public:
  virtual std::vector<Newsgroup> list_newsgroups() = 0;
  virtual std::vector<Article> list_articles(const size_t article_id) const = 0;
  virtual bool create_newsgroup(const std::string& newsgroup_name) = 0;
  virtual bool create_article(const size_t newsgroup_id, const std::string& title, const std::string& author, const std::string& text) = 0;
  virtual bool delete_newsgroup(const size_t newsgroup_id) = 0;
  virtual std::pair<int,Article> get_article(const size_t newsgroup_id, const size_t article_id) const = 0 ;
  virtual int delete_article(const size_t newsgroup_id, const size_t article_id) = 0;
};
```

And in my class that uses the database, I have these lines:

```
string file_memory;
DatabaseMemory db;
try {
  file_memory = argv[2];
  if(file_memory.compare("-file") == 0 || file_memory.compare("-f") == 0 ) {
     DatabaseFile db;
     cout << file_memory << endl;
  } else if (file_memory.compare("-memory") == 0 || file_memory.compare("-m") == 0 ) {
        DatabaseMemory db;
  } else {
     cerr << "Specify saving on disk with '-f' or in memory with '-m' " << endl;
     exit(1);
  }
  } catch ( exception& e ) {
  cerr << "Specify saving on disk or in memory" << endl;
  exit(1);
```

}

As you can see I'm trying to initialize a derived DatabaseMemory just to please the compiler, however, this seems like a shoddy approach. How would I go about making this better?

I want to be able to write something like

```
 DatabaseInterface db;
if(file_memory == "-m") {
    db = DatabaseMemory();
} else if ( file_memory == "-f") {
    db = DatabaseFile();
} else {
exit(1);
}
//.... do stuff
```

How do I go about doing this? At this point , my interface gives me nothing. I think I may have missed the point of using it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need indirection (i.e. a pointer or reference to the base class) to support polymorphism. Something like

```
std::unique_ptr<DatabaseInterface> db;
if (file_memory == "-f") {
    db = std::make_unique<DatabaseFile>();
} else if (file_memory == "-m") {
    db = std::make_unique<DatabaseMemory>();
}
```

If you're not using C++14 yet, you can replace `make_unique` with

```
db.reset(new DatabaseFile);
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Although, shouldn't it be the opposite for make_unique? e.g if "-f" then make unique of DatabaseFile, and vice-versa? Regards

Comment: @enrm: That would make more sense. I just copied the flags from your final code snippet without thinking too much about what they might mean.

Comment: What compiler is needed to use make_unique ? Im using g++ 4.9.2, It doesn't recognize make_unique..

Comment: @enrm: You'll need C++14 for that. Or change it to `db.reset(new DatabaseFile)` if you're still working with C++11.